# Active Directory access using HostingEnvironment.Impersonate() fails to find the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, active-directory

I have looked at every posting regarding the reasons for the following exception:

> ```
> An unhandled exception has occurred. 
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
> at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()
> ```

It appears that the best solution for this issue is to use HostingEnvironment.Impersonate() when calling DirectorySearcher as suggested in many links including the ones below:
[Active Directory COM Exception - An operations error occurred (0x80072020)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285503/active-directory-com-exception-an-operations-error-occured-0x80072020/16902773#16902773)
and
[Getting Error Querying Active Directory On The Server Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010141/getting-error-querying-active-directory-on-the-server-only)
I encapsulated my code for accessing DirectorySearcher in 
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate()) as suggested and it stopped getting the exception but it cannot find the user.
The only way I have seen it get further is to make  in my web.config file but even that is not fetching the correct user, which is supposed to be the windows user.
Do I need to change anything in the IIS configuration?
I should mention that similar to other posts related to this subject, this code works fine in my local environment, i.e. running from VStudio on its own IIS server. I only get this when I deployed the app and attempted to run from another IIS server.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your LDAP path.

Regarding the COM Exception, I switched from "AppPoolIdentity" to "NetworkService", which solved my issue.

Comment: Not valid in all cases. Some times it throws error Login failed for user 'DomainName\MachineName$'.